# How to validate each character of a string using a regex? Validation Rule Regex or Apex Trigger?

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex

I have a text field of size 11 and have to validate each character of the string with a different set of rules. Forex. : 1st character should accept only [1-9], 2nd character should only accept certain letters such as [A-z&&[^SLO]], 3rd position should accept [1-9][A-Z]. what would be a better approach, use validation rule and a regex or apex trigger string validation?

I tried writing regex but went no further than 5 characters validation.

```
NOT( REGEX( MBI_No__c , "^[1-9](?![SLIBZ])[A-Z][1-9](?![SLIBZ])[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]") )
```

This works for 5 characters validation. Above validation works but not sure if it is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Using an Apex trigger is the worse choice, in my opinion. It requires at least the same or more effort (e.g. bulkify the trigger, ensure you are not doing the work twice on update/insert, etc.) without providing real benefits.

So, your validation rule/regex approach looks okay.

You could use a negative lookahead or a character class subtraction to assert certain characters:

E.g. do assert all lowercase vowels 
in Java <strike>Apex</strike>

```
[a-z&&[^aeiou]]
```

can be written in PCRE (PHP, R, Perl, Python & JavaScript)

```
(?![aeiou])[a-z]
```

> The negative lookahead asserts that the following character is not a
>   lowercase vowel. Then [a-z] matches a letter, which is guaranteed not
>   to be a vowel. See [Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction)

Comment: Thanks, however using `[a-z]&&[^aeiouu]` I am not achieving the result of the validation rule. Salesforce accepts negative lookaheads. I will post my final answer once I finished writing it. Thanks again for the feedback and that's the exact link that helped me with negative lookahead and I came up with 5 char. a helpful resource, do you know any best way to unit test such long regex?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing validation rule for all 11 chars, `NOT( REGEX( MBI_No__c , "^[1-9](?![SLIBZ])[A-Z][1-9](?![SLIBZ])[A-Z][A-Z_0-9][1-9]*$") )`

Above regex works up to 6 char string and can be extended to 11 char. To test, I used https://regexr.com/

Comment: Looks good to me and the pattern cannot be further optimized, IMHO.